# Normalization of ring of polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Let $x_1(t),...,x_n(t)\in\mathbb{C}[t]$ be such that $\mathbb{C}[t]$ is finite as a $\mathbb{C}[x_1(t),...,x_n(t)]$-module and that $\mathbb{C}(x_1(t),...,x_n(t))=\mathbb{C}(t)$.

> How to show that $\mathbb{C}[t]$ is the normalization of $\mathbb{C}[x_1(t),...,x_n(t)]$?

Thank you.

Comment: You want to say $\mathbb{C}[t]$ is finite as a $\mathbb{C}[x_1(t),\dots,x_n(t)]$-module, not the other way around ($\mathbb{C}[x_1(t),\dots,x_n(t)]$ is not even a $\mathbb{C}[t]$-module in general).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $A=\mathbb{C}[x_1(t),\dots,x_n(t)]$.  Assuming you meant that $\mathbb{C}[t]$ is finite as an $A$-module (the other way around does not make sense), it follows that every element of $\mathbb{C}[t]$ is integral over $A$.  Since $\mathbb{C}[t]$ is contained in the field of fractions of $A$, it follows that the normalization of $A$ contains all of $\mathbb{C}[t]$.  But $A\subseteq\mathbb{C}[t]$ and $\mathbb{C}[t]$ is integrally closed, so the normalization of $A$ is also contained in $\mathbb{C}[t]$.  Thus the normalization of $A$ is equal to $\mathbb{C}[t]$.

(In fact, if $A\subseteq\mathbb{C}(t)$ is any subring containing $\mathbb{C}$ and a nonconstant polynomial $p(t)$, then $t$ is automatically integral over $A$: namely, $x=t$ is a root of $p(x)-p(t)$, which is a polynomial in $x$ over $A$ whose leading coefficient is a unit.  So the hypothesis that $\mathbb{C}[t]$ is finite as an $A$-module is always true unless the polynomials $x_i(t)$ are all constant.)